# Compilar desde Compilado

Tags: c++, linux, windows

Tengo una aplicación que por debajo usa la linea de comandos para pasarle los argumentos al compilador y así generar un .exe (en el caso de windows) ya compilado.

Quiero publicar la aplicación, pero cada persona puede que tenga el compilador en una ruta distinta, entonces me pregunto si hay alguna forma de generar un .exe (o el compilado) desde la propia aplicación sin recurrir al compilador por linea de comandos.

Gracias!

Comment: He encontrado algo para hacerlo en memoria, aunque parece estar puramente orientado a sistemas Windows => https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6492/A-tool-for-dynamic-compile-and-run-of-C-or-VB-NET

Answer (score 2):

Para compilar el código hace falta, por definición, un compilador. O usas uno externo o adjuntas uno en tu aplicación.

- Si haces uso de un compilador externo lo suyo sería que tu aplicación leyese un fichero de configuración en el que el usuario pueda indicar dónde se encuentra el compilador (imagínate que tiene varios instalados), de qué tipo es y otra información importante para que tu programa pueda hablar correctamente con el compilador. La complejidad de esta solución está en que tu aplicación sepa hablar correctamente con diferentes compiladores (a imagen y semejanza de cualquier IDE moderno).
- Para integrar el compilador en tu aplicación podrías almacenar el binario en forma de array de bytes (tendrías que utilizar varios arrays ya que los compiladores suelen hacer uso de varias librerías). Entonces tu aplicación podría generar el ejecutable guardando dicho array en un fichero binario. El problema que plantea esta solución es que el compilador podría no funcionar correctamente con algunos sistemas operativos debido a incompatibilidades. Otro problema es que te tocará leerte las licencias del compilador para elegir uno que sea compatible con esta forma de distribución.
- Una tercera opción sería que distribuyeses el compilador junto al ejecutable, es decir, en el mismo paquete metes los dos ejecutables. Entonces podrías asumir que el compilador va a encontrarse en el raiz de la aplicación (o donde lo quieras poner). Los problemas que te enfrentas con esta solución son los mismos que en el caso anterior.

Answer (score 2):

**No**. No hay forma de generar un ejecutable desde la propia aplicación sin recurrir al compilador por línea de comandos: el compilador es un ejecutable y requiere ser invocado, seguramente mediante una llamada a [`system`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem).

---

Veo que has etiquetado la pregunta con [windows](/questions/tagged/windows), así que asumo que pretendes usar el compilador de [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio). Como bien indicas "*cada persona puede que tenga el compilador en una ruta distinta*" pero esto ya ha sido tenido en cuenta por el equipo de Microsoft, que ha preparado una [guía configurar el compilador por línea de comandos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line) (resaltado mío):

> Al elegir una de las cargas de trabajo de C++ en **el instalador de Visual Studio, instala Visual Studio conjunto de herramientas de plataforma**. Un conjunto de herramientas de plataforma dispone de herramientas de C y C++ para una versión específica de Visual Studio, **incluidos los compiladores de C o C++, vinculadores, ensambladores y otras herramientas de compilación**, así como las bibliotecas de búsqueda de coincidencias. **Puede usar todas estas herramientas en la línea de comandos**, y también se usan internamente por el IDE de Visual Studio.

> **Para que funcione correctamente, las herramientas requieren varias variables de entorno específico para establecerse**. Se utilizan para agregarlos a la ruta de acceso y establecer incluir ubicaciones de SDK, archivo de biblioteca y archivos. Para que sea más sencillo definir estas variables de entorno, **el instalador crea *archivos de comandos personalizados***, o los archivos por lotes, durante la instalación. **Puede ejecutar uno de estos archivos de comandos en una ventana del símbolo del sistema para establecer un host específico y arquitectura de compilación de destino, versión del SDK de Windows, plataforma de destino y el conjunto de herramientas de plataforma**.

> **Las variables de entorno necesarias son específicas para la instalación** y la arquitectura de compilación que elija y se puede cambiar las actualizaciones del producto. Por lo tanto, **se recomienda usar uno de los métodos abreviados del símbolo instalados o archivos de comandos en lugar de establecer las variables de entorno de Windows**.

#### Propuesta.

Te va a ser necesario seguir la guía de configuración en todas las máquinas en que quieras lanzar la compilación, una vez configurada la máquina de destino para compilar: haz la llamada `system` para lanzar la compilación.